# Strange behavior in Excel with pivotable

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

First I hope you will be able to understand my English :)

And I thank you in advance for reading my problem.

I'm in trouble with one of my workbook (Excel 2013).

I can't give you the source but I'll try to explain.

First I had a TCD built on a ListObject, a recordset fills the Listobject, which was the source of my pivottable. But sometimes there was too many lines for the listobject to handle...

So to avoid this I switched to copying my Recordset in a pivotcache which was now used to create the pivottable. This to get rid of the 1M lines limitation of excel. This is working... sometimes.

Sometimes Excel won't let me add a certain Pivotfield to my pivot table, let's call it "SEQ", it says there are too many unique elements.

But if I double clic on the grand total of my Pivottable, it details me the 260K lines which made the pivotcache in a new sheet (it's the same result of my sql query). And if I make a new pivottable on this range, then it's ok and I can add the field SEQ.

That's odd ! I found this limitation about pivot table : Maximum number of unique items in a PivotTable -  1,048,576. But i don't have that many lines, and only 67K distinct SEQ !

Why would Excel consider I've too many unique item when refering too pivotcache from a Recorset, but not when the pivot cache is based on a range in a worksheet ?

I hope I was clear enough.

Edit : Here is some code as asked

Declared in an accessible module :

`Public cnn As New ADODB.Connection`

`Public objcmd As New ADODB.Command`

In function that fetch the data and creat the PT :

```
Req = "SELECT * FROM TABLE"
objcmd.CommandText = Req
Set RS = objcmd.Execute
Set objPivotCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlExternal)
Set objPivotCache.Recordset = RS

With objPivotCache
    .CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=Range("A8"), TableName:="TCDDirect1"
End With

 With Sheets("Données").PivotTables("TCDdirect1").PivotFields("ETATR")
     .Orientation = xlRowField
     .Position = 1
 End With
 With Sheets("Données").PivotTables("TCDdirect1").PivotFields("FAMR")
     .Orientation = xlRowField
     .Position = 2
 End With
 With Sheets("Données").PivotTables("TCDdirect1").PivotFields("SEQ")  <---- Program stop here in some cases
     .Orientation = xlRowField
     .Position = 3
 End With
 With Sheets("Données").PivotTables("TCDdirect1").PivotFields("LIBELLé")
     .Orientation = xlRowField
     .Position = 4
 End With
```

Comment: `I switched to copying my Recordset in a pivotcache` How are you creating the recordset and copying it in the pivotcache? Can we see some code to begin with?

Comment: `Set objPivotCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlExternal)
 
Set objPivotCache.Recordset = RS
With objPivotCache
.CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=Range("A8"), 
TableName:="TCDdonnées" 
End With`

Comment: I can' get the code backticks to work, sry for the poor presentation.

Comment: The recordset is filled by an adodb connection

Comment: All is ok if i copy my recorset to a sheet and then build my pivot table on that range.
But if I don't copy my recordset to a sheet and use it to fill my pivot cache, then it's ok for most of the fields but not for some (SEQ for example). For those Excel says that there are too many unique items... but it's not the case ! If I .count my pivot cache I've 260K lines, how could I've too many uniques items ?

Comment: Can you update the quesiton with the code. It is difficult to read code in comments. Also can you share the code where you are filling the recordset

Comment: I added some code.

Comment: Ok one of my colleague solved the problem.

Using  Set objPivotCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlExternal) instead of Set objPivotCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlExternal) Solves the proble... I don't know why exactly...

Comment: How can I tag this question as solved ?

Comment: Post an answer and accept it

Answer (score 0):

Using Set objPivotCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlExternal) instead of Set objPivotCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlExternal) solves the problem... I don't know why exactly... hope it'll help someone !